# How to find the function of something in a photo, e.g. a road?

Tags: calculus, geometry

How do I find the graphical function of a regular arc in a photo, for example a bridge or a road? I've read about people using GeoGebra for this, but I am not sure how.

Thank you

Comment: You can use a numerical approach by using reference points. It is a common method which gets taught in school.

Comment: There is no "the function", infinitely many solutions exist. You have to give more requirements before a unique (or more importantly, interesting) solution can be identified.

Comment: You might be interested in  [Bézier curves](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve).

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://www.desmos.com/ and paste your picture as a background and trace over the picture by writing a function. This is what I have made in desmos.com. They are all written as functions.
[image]

[image]